# C++ , sending structs via tcp

Tags: c++, sockets, vector, tcp

I try to send and receive data via TCP. My problem is that I want to send 2 structs in one TCP message, is there any way to link the struct together.
Something like:

```
send(connected, struct1 + struct2, sizeof(struct1 + struct2), 0);

recv_data = recv(connected, struct1 + struct2,sizeof( struct1 + struct2),0);
```

If not would it be possible to add a signal byte at the beginning of the message something like:

```
send(connected, "0x01" + struct1, sizeof(struct1 + 1), 0);

recv_data = recv(connected, struct1,sizeof(struct1),0);
```

Comment: see std::vector::data

Comment: No, no, no, no. `sizeof(vector)` does not tell you how many bytes the contents of the vector occupy. Stop what you are doing and think about it.

Comment: sorry I missed something, I'm talking about structs. Edited the post.

Comment: Then please fix the question title.

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. By using a struct you are introducing half a dozen dependencies that will come back and bite you. Define your application protocol in octets and write yourself a library to send and receive it.

Comment: the problem is that I can't modify anything on sending side, I can only add the few lines I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [`writev`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/writev.3p.html) and [`readv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readv.3p.html) functions, which allow sending/receiving data with multiple non-contiguous memory locations.

```
struct iovec data[2];
data[0].iov_base = vector1.data();
data[0].iov_len = vector1.length() * sizeof(vector1[0]);
data[1].iov_base = vector2.data();
data[1].iov_len = vector2.length() * sizeof(vector2[0]);
writev(socket, data, 2);
```

However at the receiving side you need some way to know the number of incoming elements so you can reserve enough space to read into.

This will also only work for vectors of trivially-copyable objects, not something like `std::vector<std::string>`.

You really need to define some kind of properly-designed serialization format, not just copy raw bytes from vectors to sockets.

If you don't know how to do this properly (and your pseudo-code suggests you don't) then look at something like [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) instead.

**Edit:** ok, you're not talking about vectors, despite saying "vectors" repeatedly. For simple structs of trivial types you can do it:

```
struct iovec data[2];
data[0].iov_base = &struct1;
data[0].iov_len = sizeof(struct1);
data[1].iov_base = &struct2;
data[1].iov_len = sizeof(struct2);
writev(socket, data, 2);
```

But you *still* shouldn't just be copying raw bytes to/from sockets. This will only work if the sending and receiving machines agree on the sizes, alignments and endianness of the data types. It is still safer and more correct to use a properly-designed serialization system like Protocol Buffers. That has been designed by people who understand how to do these things correctly and safely.

Comment: sorry I missed something, I'm talking about structs. Edited the post.

Comment: whit this method I can send data, but on receiver side I receive wrong data.

Comment: **So use a properly-designed serialization format!** Otherwise you have all kinds of unsafe assumptions about object layout.